# Phonegap Push Notifications, sound but no notification

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I´m currently experiencing a problem with the push notification plug-in that i´m using on my app, and i really don´t don´t what am i doing wrong, so i was hopping someone could point me on the right direction. Here is what i am doing:

It´s an app with background geolocation, and i´m using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation) plug-in. **Whenever the user is on a certain radius, a push must happen**. The push runs correctly in Foreground and Background(app is open but the user as pressed the main button)...but **if the app is closed, the push sends a sound but the notification doesn´t appear** and this is not what i´m looking for, and regarding the background geolocation everything is working because i can see the icon on the top of the screen and when the app is downloaded it asks for geolocation even if the user is not on the app. I really think i didn´t configure the push notifications correctly, and this is my code:

**Xml file:**

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.8.2" source="npm">
        <param name="SENDER_ID" value="myNumber" />
</plugin>
```

**Js file:**( i also started everything from [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/push-notifications/))

```
onDeviceReady: function() 
{
  my code...
  app.setupPush();
},
setupPush: function() 
{
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": 
        {
            "senderID": "myNumber"
        },
        "ios": 
        {
            "sound": true,
            "vibration": true,
            "badge": true,
            "clearBadge": true
        },
        "windows": {}
    });
    push.on('registration', function(data) 
    {
        var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
        if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId)
        {

            localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
            // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
        }
        deviceToken = data.registrationId;
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) 
    {
        console.log("push error = " + e.message);
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) 
    { 
        push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() 
        {
            console.log('success');
        }, function() 
        {
            console.log('error');
        }, data.count + 1);

        navigator.notification.confirm(
        data.message, // message
        onConfirm,            
        'My Title',           // title
        ['Ok', 'X']     // buttonLabels
        ); 
   });
}
```

**Php file:**

some code to calculate the radius, and then:

```
if ($ambiente == "Android" && $haParceiros >0 ) 
{
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'myKey' );
    $registrationIds = array( $_GET['token'] );
    // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
    (
        'message'       => $pushMessage,
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
    );
    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'          => $msg
    );
    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result; 
}

else if ($ambiente == "iOS" && $haParceiros >0 ) 
{
    $device =$deviceToken;
    $passphrase = 'myPassphrase';
    // Put your alert message here:
    $title = $pushMessage;

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-dev.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'body' => $title,
            'action-loc-key' => 'Eco App',
        ),
        'content-available' => 1,
        'image' => 'icon-small.png',
        'badge' => $haParceiros,
        'sound' => 'default',
        );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

and this is it, everything works great in foreground and background, but not when the app is closed, i have read some things hover the web that i don´t know if it can influence, like:

1 - Saving the deviceToken in a database(which i´m not doing, the app registers when it´s open).

2 - the priority of the push, which i think i´m sending on the ios payload with the content available.

I´m sorry for the long issue, thanks for your time..and...Help!!.

Regards

Comment: what platform do you not see the notification when the app has been killed? iOS, Android or both?

Comment: Hello Simon, sorry for the late answer...this happens on ios...is my configuration correct? Regards

Comment: It looks correct. Can you run the app in Xcode so we can see the logs?

Comment: Actually, i never done that before, i always use my code editor, then go to the buil.phonegap to build the files...i have seen people who can use xcode with phonegap but i don´t know how to do that, sorry for the rookie comment, but could you point me on how to do it?